# Можно ли с помощью google drive получать видео для unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, google-drive

Ищу варианты для получения видео с облачного хранилища. Пришла мысль, что может как то можно получить ссылку на видео с гугл диска в приложение. Суть в том что если нужно добавить видео на сайт то там ссылка без расширения типо .mp4, а мне необходимо чтобы ссылка имела это расширение (без него Video Player в unity не распознает). Кто пытался такое может сделать?

Comment: чем ютуб не устраивает?

Comment: @tym32167 на youtube ссылку нужно преобразовать. Там тоже не прямая ссылка на видео с расширением. Мне в данной случае подойдет абсолютно любой вариант, лишь бы работало)

Comment: зачем вам прямая ссылка на файл, если вам надо добавить видео на сайт? Грузите видео на ютуб и встраивайте его сколько хотите

Comment: @tym32167 мне нужно не на сайт, а в плеер в unity

Comment: `Суть в том что если нужно добавить видео на сайт`?

Comment: А, все, понял. Странно, что ютуб не принимает ваш плеер

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet

Comment: Попробуйте dropbox, у них есть прямые ссылки, с google drive все равно будет идти преобразование ссылки при обращении.

Comment: @ArtemCherevan дропбокс пробовал, тоже преобразование идет